# What does diff with curly braces denote?

Tags: bash, shell-script

```
for i in $(find template -type f | sed 's/^template//') ; do
    diff -wBNu {,./template}$i
```

I can understand the for loop which will traverse all the files in the `template` directory and then replace all the sentence starting with template with `''`. Is this understanding correct? What does the `diff` do here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The braces perform shell 'brace expansion'. The construct {,./template}$i produces a pair of words, both containing the value of $i, but the latter has ./template prepended. Try the command

```
echo foo{,bar}
```

at the shell prompt to see it in action. This is documented under "Brace expansion" in the bash manual.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But in the for loop does the sed command replace the filename, or the content of the file?

Comment: Sed command works on its input. In this case it is the output of the find command, which is a list of found files.